# Multiple inheritance | Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Why A is not called in this code: [is it because of mro : left to right then A class should be called?]

```
class A:
    
     def __init__(self,name):
        print('inside a',name)
        
class B:
    
     def __init__(self,name):
        print('inside b',name)
        
class C(B,A):
    
     def __init__(self,name):
        print('inside c',name)
        super().__init__(name)
        
c = C('hello')
```

Output :

```
inside c hello

inside b hello
```

But when I defined it like this basically a parent class then it is working properly as expected.[Why A class is called here ]Code:

```
class D:
    
    def __init__(self,name):
        print('inside d',name)
    
class A(D):
    
     def __init__(self,name):
        print('inside a',name)
        super().__init__(name)
        
class B(D):
    
     def __init__(self,name):
        print('inside b',name)
        super().__init__(name)
        
class C(B,A):
    
    def __init__(self,name):
        print('inside c',name)
        super().__init__(name)
        
c = C('hello')
```

output:

```
inside c hello

inside b hello

inside a hello

inside d hello
```

Comment: For `super()` to work right with multiple inheritance, you have to use it in *every* class in the hierarchy - even the base classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Method resolution order, the members are searched in depth first search methodology i.e in your first example :

```
class A:
    
     def __init__(self,name):
        print('inside a',name)
class B:
    
     def __init__(self,name):
        print('inside b',name)       


class C(B,A):
    
     def __init__(self,name):
        print('inside c',name)
        super().__init__(name)
        
c = C('hello')
```

**First:** constructor of C is called.

**Second:** Since you have super().**init**(name) in you class C , it will call its left parent i.e B.

**Third:** it will try to go to right(class C) but since you have not written super().**init**(name) inside class B ,the constructor of class A can't be called because from class B it can't move to Object class

```
                            Object
                             /\
                            /  \
                           B    A
                            \  /
                             \/
                             C
```

If you will write  super().**init**(name) in class B , it will iterate from Object class to right of object i.e class A

For e.g.:

```
class A:
    
     def __init__(self,name):
        print('inside a',name)
        
class B:

     def __init__(self,name):
        print('inside b',name)
        super().__init__(name)

        
class C(B,A):
    
     def __init__(self,name):
        print('inside c',name)
        super().__init__(name)

        
c = C('hello')
```

For more visit :https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/method-resolution-order-in-python-inheritance/

Comment: You can also view C3 linearization, to understand MRO better
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20C3%20superclass%20linearization,Method%20Resolution%20Order%20(MRO)